# Will deleting a variable and recreating it right after avoid memory leaks in multiprocessing python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, python-multiprocessing

I'm currently using multiprocessing with python 3 on Windows 10 (16GB RAM, 11 cores).

I'm facing an issue with memory leaks in my script.

My question is:

By setting a variable used the most to None, then deleting it and re-create it and run a gc.collect() and adding a time.spleep() every tot number of iterations, will this help the memory leak problem?

Here below is the script (imap_unordered, credit @Roland Smith):

```
a = [('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1), ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3)] # Many more inside this list.

def hydra_gecko(item):
    file_name, initial_letter, final_letter, process_number = item
    # url and proxy details here
    response = requests.get(url)
    # parse html and gather data, return result.
    iteration_count = 0
    new_keyword = 'apple'# As an example
    new_keyword_temp_placeholder = None
    # While loop with some operations inside.
    iteration_count += 1 # At each iteration.


   # Will this block below help with memory leaks?

   # From here:
   if iteration_count == 999:
        new_keyword_temp_placeholder = new_keyword
        new_keyword = None
        del new_keyword
        new_keyword = new_keyword_temp_placeholder
        new_keyword_temp_placeholder = None
        time.sleep(180)
        gc.collect()
    else:
        continue
    # Till here.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(maxtasksperchild=4) as p:
        for result in p.imap_unordered(hydra_gecko, a):
            print(result)
```

Comment: What kind of memory problems are you running into? I'd doubt that Python actually leaks memory during runtime. Just a note on the side: make sure to reset your `iteration_count` back to 0 once it has reached 999.

Comment: thanks @jboockmann . The memory problem is that the RAM keeps growing and growing.

Comment: That is a quite normal behavior. What exactly are you processing? Are you building up a huge list of items, etc.?

Comment: Hi @jboockmann, yes, collecting data from a website. I noticed that my non-paged pool memory does not get released after closing any application and keeps building up.

Comment: your fiddling with `new_keyword` and `temp_placeholder` do nothing, that's not how Python (or most languages) work.  the following talk might help explain why https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns